# Is it necessary to keep these kernel header and image and other files that `apt autoremove` wants to remove?

Tags: apt, files

Is is necessary to keep the following files? They appeared when I ran `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

```
libllvm4.0 libllvm4.0:i386 linux-headers-4.4.0-101
linux-headers-4.4.0-101-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-21
linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-59
linux-headers-4.4.0-59-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-93
linux-headers-4.4.0-93-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-96
linux-headers-4.4.0-96-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-97
linux-headers-4.4.0-97-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-98
linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-97-generic linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-93-generic
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-97-generic
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic
```

output of uname -r:

```
4.4.0-109-generic
```

output of apt-cache policy linux-image-generic:

```
linux-image-generic:
  Installed: 4.4.0.109.114
  Candidate: 4.4.0.109.114
  Version table:
 *** 4.4.0.109.114 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.4.0.21.22 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 12):

Both your currently running kernel and the latest kernel you have installed are newer than all of the versions being suggested for removal. If you have no problems with your current kernel version, I think it's safe to go ahead and remove all the older versions. To be on the safe(r) side, you might want to reboot to the newest installed kernel and verify it works fine for you before proceeding with this.

Answer (score 4):

Generally no, not a problem.
They are only there as backups, in case you experience issues with the new kernel version, especially in the case of kernel panics.
(Those backups are the ones you see under the GRUB boot menu).

If you have no issues, feel free to remove them. Although it is generally considered a good idea, to keep the version previous to the one you are currently using.

Comment: “Although it is generally considered a good idea to keep the version previous to the one you are currently using.” APT does it automatically, doesn’t it?

Comment: @Melebius Yes, it does.

Comment: In this case it should keep all three - the current (running) version, the one before that and the latest

Comment: True, but I was talking about what they should leave alone, if they want to delete some. Sometimes APT doesn't do a good job of cleaning out the old ones. At least in my experience. :)